# Trying Get Floating-EditText Children of a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-viewgroup

I am trying to get **Floating EditText** from viewgroup (LinearLayout). Simple **EditText** Working fine but unable to get with it.

here is my code:

**XML code:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signup_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);

            if (v instanceof EditText) {

                EditText editText = (EditText) v;

                if (editText.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME + 1) {

                    isValid = validateName(et_name);

                    if (!isValid) {

                        break;
                    }

                }
```

This ( **android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout** ) is come between LinearLayout and EditText and i have no idea how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is. If you want a reference to the `EditText`, just use `findViewById()`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM for your advice! Now i have solved my issue from below mentioned answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (v instanceof TextInputLayout) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) v.getChildAt(0);
```

But you should probably add some more checks to be sure you don't run into exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

TextInputLayout has a method getEditText to retrieve the EditText inside it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#getEditText()

You should not use getChildAt to retrieve EditText.

Instead:

```
if (v instanceof TextInputLayout) {
    EditText editText = ((TextInputLayout) v).getEditText();
}
```